# How to install a minimal version of Ubuntu on low end VPS

Tags: ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install Ubuntu minimal on VPS](https://superuser.com/questions/290853/install-ubuntu-minimal-on-vps)

I am just starting out with Linux, purchased a VPS and would like to install a minimal desktop so I can open a remote desktop connection via TightVNC, how do I go about it?

This is the VPS I Have: 256 MB RAM 500 GB BW 10 GB HDD 1 IP

With Ubuntu server 10.10 installed (32 bit)

Answer (score 0):

[Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) (DSL) is a very small Linux Distrobution that is a Debian flavor ([similar to Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/community/ubuntu-and-debian)). It only requires 50MB and 128MB of RAM. If you want an OS with a small footprint, DSL is your choice.

Comment: Thanks, I only have the choice of installing Ubuntu on my server, and want the desktop counterpart for remote access.

Comment: Just make sure that SSH is installed on the DSL Box and the service is running, then you could remote into it with putty. That is what I do with my Virtual Machines.